# The local and average Nusselt number in a square cavity

Tags: matlab, finite-difference, fluid-dynamics, computational-physics

I am in the process of programming the local & average Nusselt number in a left vertical wall but my Matlab script gives me inappropriate values and it doesn't change with changing of Rayleigh number!!

The problem is: how to calculate and impliment the local Nusselt number in a vertical left wall of a cavity. The expressions of the local nusselt: $-\dfrac{\partial T}{\partial x}|_{x=0}$

My script: using finite difference approximation with 5 points-Forward scheme ( j=1 to m+1 and i=1 )

```
for j=1:m+1
    Nu_loc(j) = -(-25*T(1,j)+48*T(1+1,j)-36*T(1+2,j)+16*T(1+3,j)-3*T(1+4,j))/(12*hx);   
end
```

Comment: The Nusselt number is a dimensionless number, but your formula has units $K/m$. It can't be right.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth in this case T and x are both dimensionless parameters

Comment: OK, but I still don't understand what the question is. You are computing the derivative with a finite difference stencil that looks correct to me. What is it you want to ask? Your post has no question mark.

Comment: Mr. @WolfgangBangerth my question:  are the formulation and the implimentation above right or need to try another ones?

Comment: @Bakizza Yes, that's the definition of the heat flux, and that's a valid finite difference stencil. But that's all we can say. You don't show us how you compute $T(i,j)$, and all you say is that it is giving you "inappropriate values", which can be any number of things. We simply can't help you without more information.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider some of the references in this summary [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232964575_Summary_of_benchmark_numerical_studies_for_3-D_natural_convection_in_an_air-filled_enclosure) of a contest at a meeting to solve the 3D problem.